# Android NoSuchField error in R.java after process is killed

Tags: java, android

I've hit a very frustrating issue with one of my apps.

I have a splashscreen activity which loads up some initial data for my app then launches the main activity and finishes itself.

Once main activity is running, I background the app by pressing the home key and then kill the process for my app.

When I relaunch my app, the splashscreen tries to run but fails as soon as I try to access any of the fields in my R.java file:

For example, I immediately try to set the text of a textview like so:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.splash_tv_1)).setText(application.getLanguage().pleasewait);
```

This throws the following exception:

```
06-29 11:18:14.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21427): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.pagesuite.android.reader.framework.R$id.splash_tv_1
```

Then when I launch it again it's fine.

I get the same behaviour if I kill the app using a TaskKiller tool (something I know a lot of users will be naively using I suspect) or if the OS kills my process.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Just noticed in the logcat, just before onCreate() of this activity executes, the following is logged:

```
06-29 11:18:14.571: WARN/dalvikvm(21427): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1945 (splash_logo) in Lcom/pagesuite/android/reader/framework/R$id;
06-29 11:18:14.571: DEBUG/dalvikvm(21427): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0000
06-29 11:18:14.571: DEBUG/dalvikvm(21427): VFY: dead code 0x0002-0010 in Lcom/pagesuite/android/reader/framework/activities/PS_Splashscreen;.loadLogoImg (Lcom/pagesuite/android/reader/framework/xml/appsettings/PS_AppSettings;)V
06-29 11:18:14.571: DEBUG/dalvikvm(21427): DexOpt: couldn't find static field
06-29 11:18:14.571: WARN/dalvikvm(21427): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1946 (splash_tv_1) in Lcom/pagesuite/android/reader/framework/R$id;
06-29 11:18:14.571: DEBUG/dalvikvm(21427): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0000
06-29 11:18:14.571: DEBUG/dalvikvm(21427): VFY: dead code 0x0002-0039 in Lcom/pagesuite/android/reader/framework/activities/PS_Splashscreen;.setLanguage ()V
06-29 11:18:14.571: DEBUG/dalvikvm(21427): DexOpt: couldn't find static field
06-29 11:18:14.571: WARN/dalvikvm(21427): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1946 (splash_tv_1) in Lcom/pagesuite/android/reader/framework/R$id;
06-29 11:18:14.571: DEBUG/dalvikvm(21427): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0000
06-29 11:18:14.571: DEBUG/dalvikvm(21427): VFY: dead code 0x0002-0020 in Lcom/pagesuite/android/reader/framework/activities/PS_Splashscreen;.setTextColors ()V
```

These are the three instances where I try to access R.id in my class.

One thing to note is that I do call:

```
setContentView(R.layout.ps_splashscreen);
```

and it seems to run this line fine, so it is the R.id's specifically that seem to be missing.

EDIT:
Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splash_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/splash_tv_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Please wait"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20dip" />

    <TextView
           android:id="@+id/splash_tv_2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Loading..."
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post code and xml layout for your splash screen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

i had the same problem and it gave me

```
DexOpt: couldn't find static field
```

error because i had two layout xml files with the same name, one in an external library one in the project. I don't know if this can be useful to others :)

Comment: Yes this was the issue if I remember correctly. The id was in a layout file in the library project, I had overridden the layout file by providing a layout with the same name in the project which was using the library. However, I had not put in the item whose Id I was trying to find so at compile time the field was not generated and hence the NoSuchField exception.

Comment: I 've been searching for hours to solve this problem, and it was just that!. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm seeing this issue too.  Are you referencing a library project?  If so, a  static from R.java may be missing because Eclipse cut it out when it imported R.java into your project from another library.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26791329/1748628

Answer (score -1):

```
//Have you Define this line in your oncreat method

      setcontentview(R.layout.yourlayout);

 // clen code then run again.
```

Comment: stated in my post that I had called setcontentview - how on earth would it run successfully the first time if I wasn't defining a layout?!